# A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am creating my rdlc report through creating dataset but when i run my report this error occur "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'" i also changed the dataset name but no improvement .i give datasource through to report viewer through smart tag.

Comment: perhaps you did not `new` the dataset object i.e create a new instance ... hard to determine what the heck you are trying to do without showing the code that of which is causing you to have errors

Comment: Please try to write correct English. Many readers (myself included) aren't native speakers, you want your question to be as easy to understand as possible.

Comment: @vonbrand his english is just fine. no need to criticize...really

Comment: Are you trying to migrate the reports?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you didn't set Data Source to Report Viewer Data Sources yet.

You can check this by many ways, I will suggest you two ways followings:

In aspx file, at `ReportViewer` tag, make sure that you have `<DataSources>` setting in the `<LocalReport>` tag. See my sample code:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="Report.rdlc">
         <DataSources>
             <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="SqlDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
         </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

To set **DataSourceId** properties of `<ReportDataSource>` tag is mandatory.

Otherwise you could set report data source instance to ReportViewer in design view. See the picture below:

[image]

ReportViewer Tasks > Choose Data Source > **Data Source Instance**

Comment: I have some code that builds an ASPNET DataTable at runtime that I want to present in ReportViewer.  Could you plz tell me how I can configure ReportViewer's Data Source at RunTime?

Answer (score 0):

In case, if you are binding the DataSource to Report by code,

```
DataSet name "FinancialRatios" and Table name "FinInfo"
```

I tried by specifying DataSet and Table name separately as below

```
ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("FinancialRatios", dsFinRatios.Tables[0]);
```

and

```
ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("FinInfo", dsFinRatios.Tables[0]);
```

In both cases the error was "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'FinancialRatios_FinInfo'."

So I set the DataSource to "FinancialRatios_FinInfo" as mentioned in the error and it worked.

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/FinRatioReport.rdlc");
ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("FinancialRatios_FinInfo", dsFinRatios.Tables[0]);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
```